# Get image list in to picture box InvalidArgument=Value of '0' invalid for 'index'

Tags: vb.net

I have a listview with the name of image and the image itself.
I need to get the selected image from my imagelist in to picture box.
i have try different ways to get it work with out success all ways the same error.
I have try to make an integer variable "index" and then if the selected item is = 0 then PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(index) 
This is my code

```
Public Class Form1
Private CounterVar As Integer = 0
Dim imgList As New ImageList
Dim index As Integer
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ListView1.View = View.Details
    ListView1.Width = 500

    ListView1.Columns.Add("Image", 75, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Name", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    'ListView1.Columns.Add("Notes", 350, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.AllowColumnReorder = True

    ListView1.Columns(0).DisplayIndex = 1

    imgList.Images.Add("Male", Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Utilizador\Downloads\balloon.jpg"))
    imgList.Images.Add("Female", Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Utilizador\Downloads\cookie.jpg"))
    ListView1.SmallImageList = imgList
    Dim index As Integer
    'Select Case True
    'Case RadioButton1.Checked
    'index = 0
    'Case RadioButton2.Checked
    'index = 1
    'End Select
    index = 1
    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
    lvi.ImageIndex = index
    lvi.SubItems.Add("Woman")
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    index = 0
    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
    lvi.ImageIndex = index
    lvi.SubItems.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
End Sub


Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ListView1.Items(0).Selected = True Then

        PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(index)

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you mean `imgList` instead of `ImageList1` in `Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Tank you for replay in fact i have discovery way its give me that error , i have previous add some imaged to the imagelist but because i have try different ways to get it work i have accidentally erase all images this it is the error, i have finally get work but my image from imagelist wen i insert on my picturebox they are to small how i can change the size of it? Tank you in advance

Comment: That should be a new question, but I suspect that you need to use larger images, perhaps from different files, in the imagelist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what is the problem you are facing,but in your comment you said

> i insert on my picturebox they are to small

Firstly the way you are passing the images is not the ideal way.However if you want the image to be bigger,you can simply set the `PictureboxSizeMode` to `Stretch`.Example :

```
 PictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
```